# Django inserts AdSense Code?

Tags: django, adsense

I'm running the 1.3 Django tutorial, and have got a development server running the polls application.  In chrome, I open the web developer widget and inspect the structure of the page.  I have:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<some form stuff>
<body>
<style>code in question</style>
</html>
```

The template for this page is simply the stuff inside the body tags.  So Django is adding on everything else.  Apparently when it does so, it adds this trailing  declaration, which seems to contain Google AdSense css classes.

Anyone know what's up with that?

views.py imports my models,
Http404,
HttpResponseRediect,
HttpResponse,
RequestContext,
get_object_or_404,
render_to_response,
reverse

none of that seems to have anything to do with AdSense.  As I mentioned, I'm just running the tutorial, have not started setting up my site yet.

Comment: Interesting. Never happened to me before, but I will be watching for an answer to this question.

Comment: I'm using AdSense - as I understand the system add it's add through javascript. Well, when I run dev or start my app on server - I saw nothing like Google ads. It pay only for clicks, so they can't hide it - because it will be useless.

Comment: It can be also something, like developers left in styles and forget about it.

Comment: do you have some middleware enabled?

Comment: Can you post the full source of the page please? Somewhere like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) would be good.

Comment: @sam, my wireless isn't working on that computer today.  I will do so ASAP.

Comment: @christophe31, no, I have nothing but the basic install.

Comment: Alternatively, just tell us if anything odd comes up when viewing the source for the page.

Answer (score 2):

I can say for certainty that "Django" is not adding anything - not even the `html` and `body` tags. They are *not* present in the HTML that Chrome is receiving. However, the Chrome inspector needs your page to be a valid HTML document, so it re-interprets some things, including adding open and close tags where necessary.

If you looked at View Source instead, you would see what the page actually looks like.

Comment: That makes sense.  I do not have a way to test it right now, as mentioned above I can't get the computer online atm.  I will verify this when I can, and post the results here.  Thanks ------edit: I *did* check the source the normal way though, and it consists of just the normal Django template code.